# Append new lines to a csv from json.parse

Tags: ruby, json, parsing, csv

more sysadmin (chef) than ruby guy, so this may be a five minute fix. 
I am working on a task where i write a ruby script that pulls json data from multiple files, parses it, and writes the desired fields to a single .csv file. Basically pulling metadata about aws accounts and putting it in an accountant friendly format.

Got a lot of help from another stackoverflow on how to solve the problem for a single file, [json.parse help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21737040/ruby-extracting-fields-from-nested-json).

My issue is that I am trying to pull the same data from multiple JSON files in an array. I can get it to loop through each file with the code below.

```
require 'csv'
require "json"

delim_file = CSV.open("delimited_test.csv", "w")
aws_account_list = %w(example example2)
aws_account_list.each do |account|
json_file = File.read(account.to_s + "_aws.json")
parsed_json = JSON.parse(json_file)

delim_file = CSV.open("delimited_test.csv", "w")
# This next line could be a problem if you ran this code multiple times
delim_file << ["EbsOptimized", "PrivateDnsName", "KeyName",               "AvailabilityZone", "OwnerId"]
parsed_json['Reservations'].each do |inner_json|
inner_json['Instances'].each do |instance_json|
   delim_file << [[instance_json['EbsOptimized'].to_s,   instance_json['PrivateDnsName'], instance_json['KeyName'], instance_json['Placement']['AvailabilityZone'], inner_json['OwnerId']],[]]
 end
 delim_file.close
end

end
```

However, whenever I do it, it overwrites every time to the same single row in the .csv file. I have tried adding a \n string to the end of the array, converting the array to a string with hashes and doing a \n, but all that does is add a line to the same row that it overwrites.

How would I go about writing that it reads each json file, then appending each files metadata to a new row? This looks like a simple case of writing the right loop, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7085595/438992 E.g., open in append mode, not write mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared your file like this:

```
delim_file = CSV.open("delimited_test.csv", "w")
```

To fix your issue, all you have to do is change `"w"` to `"a"`:

```
delim_file = CSV.open("delimited_test.csv", "a")
```

See the docs for [`IO#new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-c-new) for a description of the available file modes. In short, `w` creates an empty file at the filename, overwriting anyothers, and writes to that. `a` only creates the file if it doesn't exist, and appends otherwise. Because you have it currently at `w`, it'll overwrite it each time you run the script. With `a`, it'll append to what's already there.

Comment: nail on the head. Fixed things perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open file in append mode, use

```
delim_file = CSV.open("delimited_test.csv", "a")
```

`'a' Write-only, starts at end of file if file exists, otherwise creates a new file for writing.`

`'a+' Read-write, starts at end of file if file exists, otherwise creates a new file for reading and writing'`